# How to get two matches on multiple groups

Tags: c#, regex

Invoice total section contains text

```
Sum without 20% _48,15
Vat 20% _9,63
Invoice total (EUR)_57,78
```

Tried to get Vat text and VAT sum using nested group kmtekst

```
var tekst=@"Sum without 20% _48,15
Vat 20% _9,63
Invoice total (EUR)_57,78
";

var rida = Regex.Match(tekst, @"(?si).*(?<kmtekst>Vat(_)?(\s)?(20%)?(:))?(\s)?(_)?(?<kmaks>[\d,\.]*)(\s)?.*");
```

rida.Success is true but

but

```
rida.Groups["kmaks"].Value
```

and

```
rida.Groups["kmtekst"].Value
```

are empty. How get

`9,63` as `rida.Groups["kmaks"].Value`

and

`Vat 20%` as `rida.Groups["kmtekst"].Value` ?

Using .NET 7 ASP.NET MVC controller Rexgep

Comment: Why use regex at all? If you split your input string by newlines, both pieces of information you're interested in are on the second line, and before/after the underscore.

Comment: Why does your regex contain a colon character match when no colon exists in your input string? Your regex pattern seems overly complicated for what you've said you're trying to do.

Comment: Use `(?si)(?<kmtekst>Vat[_\s]*20%?).*?(?<kmaks>\d[\d,.]*)` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nHokIm/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why `[_\s]`? There are no underscores between "Vat" and "20%"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following.

```cs
var rida = Regex.Match(tekst, @"(?<kmtekst>Vat.+%).+?(?<kmaks>\d.+)");
```